# Code Sign Identity Missing

Tags: xcode, sign

I am trying to submit my Mac Application to the AppStore, but I cannot see the 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer identity under Code Signing.

I have downloaded both the Application and Installer certificates and they both show in Keychain, but only the Application identity shows in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem,

The time I tried it, I had neither the Application or Installer cert installed, so it was refusing it outright, but only warned me about the Installer cert.

I must have read somewhere that i *needed* to sigh the application using the Installer cert, but the guys on the DevForums told me I needed the sign the application with the Application cert, and then when submitting the application the sheet will prompt me to sign it with the Installer cert.

If anybody has the same problem, there is your answer.